# NSString stringWithUTF8String return null on device, but ok on simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, ios5

I have a really weird problem. Basically just convert a char to nsstring and store them in an nsmutable array.

But the code runs ok on simulator, but crash on device.

Here is the crash code,

```
char t = 'A' + i;
NSString* alphabetString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:&t]; //substringToIndex:1];
[tempArray addObject:alphabetString];
```

Basically the stringWithUTF8String will return NULL on device, but return valid value on simulator.

```
The device is an iPhone 4s. 

I did not see any notification of changes on NSString stringwithutf8string on iOS5 release.

 Thanks.
```

Comment: what you are trying to achieve by this: char t = 'A' + i; This is the place it's causing the problem I suspect. Then you are passing the reference of character lateral in stringWithUTF8String method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The address of a single `char` is *not* a C-style string. You need to ensure it's null terminated with something like:

```
char t = 'A' + i;
char s[2]; s[0] = t; s[1] = '\0';
NSString* alphabetString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:s];
```

From the [docpage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSString):

> **Parameters**
>        *bytes* : A NULL-terminated C array of bytes in UTF8 encoding.

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass the address of a single `char` value to `-stringWithUTF8String`.  That function is expecting a null-terminated string, and you're not passing it one.  This results in *undefined behavior*: anything at all could happen.  It might appear to succeed, it might fail benignly, or it might erase your file system.  But more likely, it will just crash your program.

You should create a two-character array that's null-terminated instead:

```
char t[2] = {'A' + i, 0};  // Two-character null-terminated array
NSString* alphabetString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:t];
```

Alternatively, you can also use `-stringWithFormat:` with the `%c` format specifier to get a string containing a single character:

```
NSString* alphabetString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", 'A' + i];
```